# How to check if a variable crossed certian value in php

Tags: php, database

I'm using php to build a dynamic site. In my DB I have an field named `points` in table `siteuser`, which is the points of the site user.

It is loaded to variable `$points` in the controller. Every time point increases the value in variable in updated to the field. A flash message will be displayed at point were the point value crosses 100.

I am having trouble in checking if the `$points` crossed 100 mark. If I write the condition as

```
if($points>=100) {echo msg;}
```

The message will appear for all values above 100. The Message should only be displayed once. So, how to write the condition?

Comment: `if($points==100)` use this

Comment: But the points are not increasing by 1, or 10. Different activities will give you different points. like 15, 20, 15 etc. So, from 90, a user may get 20 points and move to 110. What to do in such a case??

Comment: if i understood fully let's say you have four point some think like this 99,102,105 and 108, what you want to is to show the message when ever user jump the hundred, in this case only for 102 not for 105 and 108, to do that you simply add one more column in your database, that you already displayed that user message, if i am wrong or you dont understand what i am trying to say let me know, its not that difficult what you are trying achieve,

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here as this is very simple logic.

Option 1: Keep your if statement as it is and simply add a boolean for if the message has already been displayed.

```
$msg_flag = false;
if ($points >= 100 && !$msg_flag) {
    $msg_flag = true;
    echo $msg;
}
```

Option 2: Assume that points are only incremented by a value of 1 and therefore only display the message on a value of 100

```
if ($points === 100) {
    echo $msg;
}
```

Option 3: Add a second table for logging a users milestones such as when they reach a certain amount of points. Basically you will query this table to check if a record for the 100 point milestone exists for a specific user. If one does not display the message to the user and then create a milestone record.

This approach would also be good if you intend to have some sort of achievement timeline display area so that a user can see his/her progress over time and when certain milestones were reached.

Comment: The points are not increasing by 1, or 10. Different activities will give you different points. like 15, 20, 15 etc. So, from 90, a user may get 20 points and move to 110. we can rule out option 2.

Comment: @J'DeV Updated answer with a 3rd option

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
if($points>=100 && $_SESSION['isdisplay']=='notDisplayed')
{
  echo msg;
  $_SESSION['isdisplay']='displayed';
}
```

So this will show only once when it will reach to 100.

Comment: I think this will do the trick for me. In case I need to show another message at points>1000, I can use the following code: if($points>=100 && $points<=950 && $_SESSION['isdisplay']=='notDisplayed')
{
  echo msg;
  $_SESSION['isdisplay']='displayed';
}points>1000,  if($points>950)
{
  $_SESSION['isdisplay']='notDisplayed';
}

Answer (score -1):

```
 $variable = select <your_column_name> from table_name where <your_dynamic_value> > 100;echo $variable;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)